# react-native - Pod install stucked at cloning spec repo

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

All in a sudden when i tried to add new pods to the Podfile and tried to install them, the process is getting infinite!
Here is my Podfile:

```
# Podfile content
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyProject' do
    # React Native
    rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'
    rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'

    pod 'yoga', :path => "#{rn_path}/ReactCommon/yoga"
    pod 'RNSVG', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-svg'
    pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
    pod 'React', path: "#{rn_path}", :subspecs => [    
      'Core',
      'CxxBridge',
      'RCTActionSheet',
      'RCTAnimation',
      'RCTGeolocation',
      'RCTImage',
      'RCTLinkingIOS',
      'RCTNetwork',
      'RCTSettings',
      'RCTText',
      'RCTVibration',
      'RCTWebSocket',
      'DevSupport'
    ]
    pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec"
    pod 'glog', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec"
    pod 'Folly', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec"

    # Required by Google Map, ignore if you use Apple Map
    pod 'GoogleMaps', '2.5.0'
    pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils', '2.1.0'
    pod 'GoogleUtilities', '5.3.7'
    pod 'GoogleAppMeasurement', '5.4'

    pod 'react-native-maps', path: rn_maps_path
    pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: rn_maps_path # <~~ if you need GoogleMaps support on iOS
  pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'

  pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-device-info'

  pod 'RNKeychain', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-keychain'

  pod 'RNSecureRandom', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-securerandom'

  pod 'RNShare', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-share'

  pod 'react-native-image-picker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker'

  pod 'react-native-image-resizer', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-resizer'

  pod 'RNFS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fs'

  pod 'RNScrypt', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-scrypt'

  pod 'react-native-randombytes', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-randombytes'

  pod 'RNOS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-os'

  pod 'TcpSockets', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-tcp'

  pod 'react-native-udp', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-udp'

  pod 'react-native-aes', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-aes-crypto'

  pod 'BVLinearGradient', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'

  pod 'RNFBApp', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app'

  pod 'RNFBMessaging', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging'

end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == "react-native-google-maps"
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No'
            end
        end
        if target.name == "React"
          target.remove_from_project
        end

        targets_to_ignore = %w(React yoga)
        if targets_to_ignore.include? target.name
          target.remove_from_project
        end
    end
end
```

Here is the log:

```
  Preparing

Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-MyProject`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `BVLinearGradient` from `../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient`
-> Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
-> Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
-> Fetching podspec for `RNCAsyncStorage` from `../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage`
-> Fetching podspec for `RNDeviceInfo` from `../node_modules/react-native-device-info`
-> Fetching podspec for `RNFBApp` from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app`
-> Fetching podspec for `RNFBMessaging` from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging`
-> Fetching podspec for `RNFS` from `../node_modules/react-native-fs`
-> Fetching podspec for `RNKeychain` from `../node_modules/react-native-keychain`
-> Fetching podspec for `RNOS` from `../node_modules/react-native-os`
-> Fetching podspec for `RNSVG` from `../node_modules/react-native-svg`
-> Fetching podspec for `RNScrypt` from `../node_modules/react-native-scrypt`
-> Fetching podspec for `RNSecureRandom` from `../node_modules/react-native-securerandom`
-> Fetching podspec for `RNShare` from `../node_modules/react-native-share`
-> Fetching podspec for `RNVectorIcons` from `../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons`
-> Fetching podspec for `React` from `../node_modules/react-native`
-> Fetching podspec for `TcpSockets` from `../node_modules/react-native-tcp`
-> Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
-> Fetching podspec for `react-native-aes` from `../node_modules/react-native-aes-crypto`
-> Fetching podspec for `react-native-google-maps` from `../node_modules/react-native-maps`
-> Fetching podspec for `react-native-image-picker` from `../node_modules/react-native-image-picker`
-> Fetching podspec for `react-native-image-resizer` from `../node_modules/react-native-image-resizer`
-> Fetching podspec for `react-native-maps` from `../node_modules/react-native-maps`
-> Fetching podspec for `react-native-randombytes` from `../node_modules/react-native-randombytes`
-> Fetching podspec for `react-native-udp` from `../node_modules/react-native-udp`
-> Fetching podspec for `yoga` from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because
  checking is only perfomed in repo update

Cloning spec repo `cocoapods` from `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git`
  $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git -- cocoapods
  Cloning into 'cocoapods'...
```

And it gets stuck here and when i checked the activity indicator a process called `git-remote-https` is continuosly fetching the source from the repo, but it doesnt end either! Why so?? How to fix it

Comment: Have you changed anything inside pod file ?

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar I've edited and added my podfile along with.

Comment: What dependency did you add new?

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar react-native-firebase packages

Answer (score 18):

Change 
`source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'` 
to 
`source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'`

Note this requires CocoaPods 1.8.0 or newer. See `pod --version`

Comment: How to change the source??

Comment: It's line 2 of the Podfile pasted in the question.

Comment: oops! yeah..i got confused. Thanks mate.